# Alternating Cycle (T)op/(B)ottom Sequence

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Needing either a single array formula or one dragged down the column that will show alternating sequence per a rule set.  Ruleset and detailed example are within the attached link here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sdi1jFpBKF2RJeqWNjLybVcwR0G6hvozZZTvcTK1xis/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**let cell E79 be:**

```
=IF(E79>55, "T", 
 IF(E79<45, "B",
 LOOKUP(MIN(MAX(INDEX(E2:E78,
 MATCH(1,INDEX((E2:E78>55)+(E2:E78<45)*(E2:E78<>""), ), 0)), 45), 55), 
 {45,55}, {"B", "T"})))
```

[image: 0]

---

**paste this in cell E78 and drag it upwards:**

```
=IF(((E78<55)*(E78>45))*((E79<55)*(E79>45)),, 
 IF((QUERY({F79:F},"where Col1 is not null limit 1", 0)="T")*(E78<=55)*(E79>=45), "B", 
 IF((QUERY({F79:F},"where Col1 is not null limit 1", 0)="B")*(E78> 45)*(E79< 55), "T", )))
```

[image: 0]

---

**paste this in G2 cell:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SORT({VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), )))), IF(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), ))), ROW(
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), ))))}, 2, 0),,1)<>"", {ROW(
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), )))),INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), ))), ROW(
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), ))))}, 2, 0),,1)}), 2, 1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("F2:F"&MAX(IF(F2:F<>"", ROW(F2:F), ))))}, 2, 0),,1))
```

[image: 0]

---

**and paste this in H2 cell:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(G2:G="T", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, {QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT("♦"&QUERY(IF(G2:G="T", C2:C, )&
 IF(F2:F<>"", "♦", ),,999^99), "♦")), " ")*1, "where Col1 is not null", 0)),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(FILTER(F2:F, F2:F="T")), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(F2:F)-ROW(F2)+1&")", ))&"")), "select Col2"), 
 FILTER(F2:F, F2:F="T")}, 2, 0)), 
 IF(G2:G="B", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, {QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT("♦"&QUERY(IF(G2:G="B", D2:D, )&
 IF(F2:F<>"", "♦", ),,999^99), "♦")), " ")*1), "^0$", "999999999")*1, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)), "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 IF(LEN(FILTER(F2:F, F2:F="B")), 
 "min(Col"&ROW(F2:F)-ROW(F2)+1&")", ))&"")), "select Col2"), 
 FILTER(F2:F, F2:F="B")}, 2, 0)), )))
```

[image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sdi1jFpBKF2RJeqWNjLybVcwR0G6hvozZZTvcTK1xis/edit#gid=837101805)

Comment: Far as I can tell this works perfectly.  Bravo!!!  I have been searching for help on this for months and you cracked the code.  Thank you so much!  When I am able how can I return the favor?

Comment: Hmm... Guess we are not out of the woods yet.  Would you mind troubleshooting please?  It seems that with a different data set as I have in new sheet tab "Copy 2 of Second Attempt" it is doubling up some.  I have only noticed this happening with the "T" showing twice in sequence.

Comment: In sheet tab example "Copy 2 of Second Attempt" when High/Low price has duplicate values it puts in more than one "T" or "B" in a row instead of alternating.

Comment: In sheet tab "Copy 3 of Second Attempt" not sure what is causing double "T"?

Comment: yeah, this is caused by VLOOKUP... fix would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6bR7.png

Comment: Will you please look at sheet tab "Copy 4 of Second Attempt".  Found another problem. I wish I could help you on this other than just reporting the problem.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: haha, yeah, that's caused by native rounding of too many decimals... fixed by removing few zeros: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IMK1.png

Comment: Will you please be so patient to look again at sheet tab "Copy 5 of Second Attempt".  You are getting closer.  As it is only failing about one out of 10 times now. Thanks again!

Comment: It is now perfect!!!  I almost can't believe it.  Been trying to get this solved for months. I tested and it was flawless after 300 samples.  99% sure I won't be needing you to look at it again.  Thanks! Take care.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)), 
 MIN(FILTER(C2:C, D2:D<45, D2:D<>"")), 1, 0))<>"", "B", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Will this array formula of which I am very unfamiliar with allow for continuation if the next one up would be searching for:  "Highest price between last cell in Row E that equals "B" and Next number in Row D that equals <55.

Comment: in this state no, but it could be done I guess. depends on how you calculate/input E11 and what logic is there (to be honest I have no idea whats going on in your sheet)

Comment: Good day to you!  Ok, so I have created another sheet tab called "Second Attempt".  I have detailed out to help as much possible.  This one formula has baffled me for a long long time and has been the cause of delay in me finishing out my project.  Your help with this is GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: If this can be done as an array formula then all the power to ya.  In the last few posts you opened my eyes to array formulas.  I didn't know so much could be done with them.  If can't be done as an array, then so be it.  I just need to try and get this working soon.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: okay, so if I understood correctly, you want arrayformula to cover range G2:G79 and generate T/B sequence from bottom of the sheet to the top of the sheet (eg. reversed) and the sequence should alternate based from starting point which is cell  E80 (so if E80 is T then appropriate value above would be B and vice versa). and rules are only two which are ">55" (T) and "<45" (B). is that all right?

Comment: Yes, but an overlapping rule written in J8 and J9 explains that for the middle range of 45-55 it also needs to allow for T& B. It has to be that way because I need to include the middle range.  If the first (>55 or <45) don't exist then second part of formula need to look for if either prior was "T" and >=45 OR prior was"B" and <=55.  It might sound contradictory but it's not. By combining these rules there will always be an alternating sequence of T,B,T,B

Comment: I placed a detailed breakdown in the note in cell G31. .  This is a puzzle for sure.  It only makes sense when you understand the cycle goes up and down, and sometimes switches in the middle range of which we still need a T or B.  Thank you greatly in advance for your time.  This is a huge favor to me.

Comment: That will be fine.  Will they be array formulas so to hopefully calculate fairly quickly.  Again, sure appreciate your help!

Comment: Will you please take another quick look at this? 
Should be "B" as CH42 has dropped below 55 (34) from the previous 68.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Dkby0AR8ojdzv4zAO614dJFewb3hjF35783cb_Lf-g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What do I need to add to this formula to skip (not return a result) if a row is blank (in particular formula runs from row 4 through 162, but row 5 is always blank.)? This formula is in cell M4 of my sample sheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDdeMmk_VsM_UkxrUYT_F4I8sINa7Y5nOnOcHxmF6Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DAK7 try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze7CZ.png

Comment: It doesn't allow for the formula to care through. Skipping the blank should mean it puts the next alternating "B" in cell M7 for this example.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "carry through"

Comment: @DAK7 try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gInjO.png (see your sheet)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but that shifts the other results down the column.

Comment: @DAK7 maybe try to change `;"";"";` to just `;"";`

Comment: Oh, I see that this won't work.  Skipping row 5 is all we want to accomplish, not shift everything down the column.  My guess is that somehow in the original formula it is thinking Cell D5 is the lowest value at the top of column D when it is actually D7.  Applied changes should only move the "B" from cell M5 to M7.